# python group by and count() multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like this:

```
Country  A B C
UK       1 0 1
US       1 1 1
GB       0 1 1
UK       1 1 1
US       0 1 1
GB       0 1 1
```

I need to groupby country and count in all columns where value is 1. I'm stuck on setting the condition of columns == 1 for all them.

The result should be something like:

```
Country  A B C
UK       2 0 2
US       1 2 2
GB       0 2 2
```

Comment: I don't understand your conditions, sum columns where all rows are 1?Why is `UK` 2,0,2 and not 2,1,2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are counting 1's you can just `groupby([]).sum()`

```py
df['country'] = df.index # to generate a new column
result = df.groupby(['country']).sum()
```

This gives you the result:

```py
         a  b  c
country         
GB       0  2  2
UK       2  1  2
US       1  2  2
```

More information
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

Comment: This returns `2,1,2` for the column `UK` and not `2,0,2` as OP requested.

Comment: I assumed it was a typo