# Group by client_id and count belonging events in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm new to Python and am dealing with a situation where I have a dataset like this:

```
client_id    event_name
123          event_1
1234         event_1
123          event_2
12           event_1
123          event_1
```

I want to adjust my dataset, so that events are counted per client, like this:

```
client_id    event_1  event_2
123          2        1
1234         1        0
12           1        0
```

What I'm aiming for is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58161230/python-group-by-and-count-multiple-columns) topic, but my events are in the same column (event_name) and need to be split up in various columns (event_1, event_2, etc).

I have been struggling with this for a day now, and I think that Python probably has a simple solution for this that I currently just don't see. It would be great if somebody could help me out!

Comment: This is the definition of [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html). There's definitely a dup somewhere. `pd.crosstab(df.client_id, df.event_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df` data frame looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'client_id': [123, 1234, 123, 12, 123], 'event_name': ['event_1', 'event_1', 'event_2', 'event_1', 'event_1']})
>>> print(df)
   client_id event_name
0        123    event_1
1       1234    event_1
2        123    event_2
3         12    event_1
4        123    event_1
```

You can use [`pandas.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) as following.

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='client_id', columns='event_name', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
event_name  event_1  event_2
client_id                   
12                1        0
123               2        1
1234              1        0
```

Comment: I knew it had to be simple... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please [group by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) client-id, [count_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) of each event and unstack .

```
data.groupby('client_id')['event_name'].value_counts().unstack().reset_index(drop=False)
```